# can't insert submodule Vue.js

Tags: javascript, module, webpack, vue.js

I am using vue.js modules, and what I am trying to do is to call a submodule inside a template module. The way i do it here doesn't work and I can't figure out why or how to fix it. The error i get is this:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'modal.vue' in /Users/..
```

The problem is not in submodule itself, since I can call it on its own. 
 I would appreciate any help or documentation references.

```
<template>
       <div class="modal fade" id='modal' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="vertical-alignment-helper"><div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div v-component="contentmodal"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div>
       </div>
</template>
<script>
module.exports = {
    created: function () {
        console.log('An instance of modal has been created!')
    },
    methods: {  
    },
    components: {
        contentmodal: require('modalcontent.vue')
    }
}
</script>
```

The template module and the submodule(modulecontent.vue) are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

I figured why. In vue.js even if 2 files are in the same directory ./ is necessary. Now, it worked. 
contentmodal: require('./modalcontent.vue')

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is on the webpack loaders. It tries to look from libraries if the path is not preceded with './' or '../'.